# Send a list with appointments through WCF

Tags: wcf, exchangewebservices, generic-list, appointment

I would like to send a list of `Appointment`s through WCF. My Interface looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IServices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string addAppointments(List<Appointment> appointmentList);
    }
```

If I call my WCF Service I'm always getting the following error:

> Type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment' cannot be
>   serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.

My Service currently looks like this:

```
class Service : IServices 
    {
        public string addAppointments(List<Appointment> appointmentList)
        {
            foreach (Appointment app in appointmentList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(app.Organizer.Name);
            }
            return "true";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment` is a class you got from elsewhere and it's not intended to be serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your service that's at fault, it's the class your passing, Appointment.
Start by adding [DataContract] to your class. then [DataMember] to each of the properties you'd like to pass.

For example, if you started with:

```
public class Appointment{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can make it serializable by WCF's DataContractSerializer by adding those attributes:

```
[DataContract]    
public class Appointment{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In which dll can I find the DataContract? I tried it with "using System.Runtime.Serialization" but it does not work for me

Comment: If OP doesn't have any [DataContract] attribute on the Entity, it will take a default approach and serialize all public properties. As per @Jesse Slicer, it seems the entity isn't a POCO and can't be serialized. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx